# Output to two streams simultaneously

Tags: c, gcc

I was asked to implement two generic dynamic sets for a University assignment, and as part of the feature set, I designed a rather crude benchmark to give me a rough idea of how efficiently the algorithms perform. Apart from showing the benchmark results in the console, I would also like to save the result to disk. So far, I've been using `printf` and a subsequent call to `fprintf` to save the same format string to disk.

```
printf("Average time: %2.8f seconds || Total: %2.8f seconds\n", totalTime/50, totalTime);
fprintf(fp, "Average time: %2.8f seconds || Total: %2.8f seconds\n", totalTime/50, totalTime);
```

Would it be possible to do it all in one go in C? i.e. place the output on two streams simultaneously? I'd appreciate any tips. My code must comply to the gnu90 standard as per our instructions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you need something like `tee` command in Linux, right?

Comment: I wouldn't know, sorry.

Comment: `whatis tee: tee - duplicating pipe content`

Comment: I did a quick Google search for `tee`, and yes, that is precisely what I need :)

Comment: One way to do that is first redirect the output to your log file and then read the file to print that output to the screen.

Comment: If you're asking whether there's a single library function that writes the same thing to two streams at once: No. I'd suggest writing your own function which encapsulates the the concept. The right answer would be to make it a `varargs` function, like the `printf` and `fprintf` it would be wrapped around... but if you haven't learned how to use varargs yet, you could just have however many different methods you need to handle the different combinations of arguments and argument types, or you could generate the string first and just have the subroutine deal with the dual output.

Comment: I never heard about a function in C that perform job like `tee` command in Linux (I am not sure about it). Hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) will help.

Comment: Why the need for simultaneous output? If anything, you could print to the file first and stdout later, so the file would have been written to before the user sees output

Comment: Or you could use `snprintf` to write formatted output to a sized buffer and then write that buffer to the streams instead of having to repeat `"Average time: %2.8f seconds || Total: %2.8f seconds\n", totalTime/50, totalTime` twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in function that does exactly what you want; so consider writing one. An interesting aspect of printf is that it's a variadic function; fortunately, the printf family is designed to make it easy to do this sort of thing. Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

int stdout_fprintf(FILE * restrict stream, const char * restrict format, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, format);
    vprintf(format, ap);
    int result = vfprintf(stream, format, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Writing a function that writes to stdio and then writes to a file, then calling that function is the same thing as writing to both stdio and the file simultaneously?

Comment: Define "simultaneously". As observed from a single thread, neither stream has data written to it before the call, and both have it written after the call; this is the same semantics as Connor's original code, but without the error-prone duplication of format strings etc. Agreed that if the concern is wall time rather than code quality this doesn't gain you anything, but the question gives no indication that that's the case.

Comment: I have to agree, OP's reason for wanting simultaneous output is unknown and seems unnecessary. Still, this method seems to add more overhead than is necessary

Comment: Fair enough. Another alternative, which I avoided for aesthetic reasons, is to use a variadic macro. Again, this would maintain the same semantics as the original code (no externally-observed simultaneity), but would avoid the overhead of the function proposed, at the cost of all the usual macro concerns. Pretty sure that gnu90 supports variadic macros of one form or another.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. As you said, it's more of an aesthetic issue. Two very similar functions calls do seem to add unnecessary clutter to the source code.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at the  [source code of a tee implementation](https://www.opensource.apple.com/source/shell_cmds/shell_cmds-170/tee/tee.c). The method used there is to:

- keep a linked list of file descriptors to duplicate output to
- for each chunk of output read from the source:

  - iterate through that list, writing to each stream

In your case, it's easier to make a wrapper function. Here's an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

int bothprintf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...) {
    va_list args;
    int ret;

    va_start(args, format);
    vfprintf(stream, format, args);
    va_end(args);

    va_start(args, format);
    ret = vprintf(format, args);
    va_end(args);

    return ret;
}
```

The ***v***printf family is the same as the usual printf with the difference that it takes its arguments in the form of a va_list, making it simple to use for things like these.

Obviously you can't keep both return values in a simple manner. This example uses the return value of (v)printf.

Answer (score 0):

`printf(...)` is equivalent to `fprintf(stdout,...)`, where `stdout` is a `FILE` pointer.

This means that your program essentially writes data into two different files, hence needs to perform two separate file-write operations.

So in short, the answer is - No, you cannot "do it all in one go in C".